# Binding to a specific IP address and port to receive UDP data

Tags: java, c, udp, bind

I am trying to receive UDP data that is broadcast to network address 192.168.103.255 port 3000 by PlayCap (http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/). I'm having problems binding to this address and port. Here's my Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.103.255", 3000);
        s.bind(address);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        s.receive(packet);
        System.out.println("Received!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This returns the error:

```
java.net.SocketException: already bound
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at runner.main(runner.java:12)
```

I have run the command "netstat -a -n", and neither address 192.168.103.255 nor port 3000 are listed anywhere in the output, so I don't think this port is already in use. In fact, I get this error for any address/port combination I try (including my static IP address).

I also wrote some C code to make a socket and bind to this address and port, but it also fails on the bind call. This code, however, will bind to ports on my static IP address (192.168.1.149). Here's that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define a1 192
#define a2 168
#define a3 103
#define a4 255
#define PORT 3000

int main() {

    /* Open windows connection */
    WSADATA w;
    if (WSAStartup(0x0101, &w) != 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open Windows connection.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Clear out server struct */
    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    memset((void *)&server, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    /* Set family and port */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = (unsigned char)a1;
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = (unsigned char)a2;
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = (unsigned char)a3;
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = (unsigned char)a4;

    /* Open a datagram socket */
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sd == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Bind address to socket */
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not bind name to socket.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Receive */
    char data[1024];
    printf("Waiting to receive...\n");
    if (recv(sd, (char *)&data, (int)sizeof(data), 0))
    {
        printf("Error receiving data.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Data: %s", data);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a Windows 7 machine. I'm running the Java code in Eclipse. I'm compiling the C code with MinGW using the command:

```
gcc a.c -lws2_32
```

("a.c" is the file name).

While the Java code is more important, I would be happy to know where I'm going wrong in either of my code examples. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: What are the Win32 errors? Why static IP?

Comment: why you are saying "broadcast" and then static IP??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this for your Java code instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.103.255", 3000);
        s.bind(address);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Calling the no-arg constructor for a datagram socket will cause it to bind to a random, available port. Once bound, further attempts to (re)bind will throw a socket exception (with the error you were seeing). To 'defer' binding, you instead create the datagram socket in an unbound state (by passing a null in the constructor), then calling `bind` later on.

Comment: Getting this error: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at runner.main(runner.java:11)

Comment: @ajlitzau13: My answer explains *why* that is.

Comment: Try binding to your default interface, to eliminate IPv6 issues (remove the internet address and just use the port).

Comment: @BenJackson - your answer does not provide an explanation for the error the OP is encountering, sorry.

Comment: @Perception: If I pass 3000 into the DatagramSocket constructor and eliminate the two lines after that, it does bind to 0.0.0.0:3000 (verified with netstat), but when I play the data back with PlayCap, nothing is received (I edited my original Java code to receive some data after binding.)

Comment: If you can bind without the IP address specified then you are either passing in an incorrect IPv4 address, or your interface is configured for IPv6. What does ipconfig /a report for all your network interfaces?

Comment: What do you mean by an incorrect IP address? Here is my ipconfig output: http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~litzau1/ipconfig.txt

Comment: Try binding to fe80::ccdd:1d08:e297:2884%10, same port.

Comment: This gives the same result as before - 0.0.0.0:3000 is bound, but no data (which PlayCap is broadcasting) is received.

Comment: Ok, the bind problem is solved, please post the receive problem as a separate question.

Comment: I have one more concern: Will I be able to receive data being broadcast to the IP address 192.168.103.255 port 3000 if I don't specify the IP address 192.168.103.255 anywhere in my code? As it is, I'm only specifying port 3000 with your solution.

Comment: How is the data getting sent from PlayCap? You might want to run a packet capture to find out. Also, if my answer helped solve your original problem please feel free to upvote and accept it.

Comment: For future reference, what finally solved my problem was setting my static IP address to something in the 192.168.103.xxx range. Since the data was being broadcast to 192.168.103.255, I couldn't receive it unless my IP was in this range. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't bind to the broadcast address to receive broadcast packets.  Just bind to the port and the address `INADDR_ANY` (sorry, not sure how to express that in Java) and you will get packets to that port on the broadcast address.

Comment: @KirillKobelev:  I think "listen on a port/address" is understood as binding to a particular address, but I clarified the wording.

Comment: I replaced the 4 lines assigning the server address with just "server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);". I also added sections to both codes to receive some data (edited my OP). Now, my C code successfully binds 0.0.0.0:3000 (verified with netstat), but when I run PlayCap to play the data back, nothing is received. Does my receive code look ok?

Comment: For future reference, what finally solved my problem was setting my static IP address to something in the 192.168.103.xxx range. Since the data was being broadcast to 192.168.103.255, I couldn't receive it unless my IP was in this range. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It [appears that](http://www.heimetli.ch/udp/UDPServer.html) the Datagram constructor takes the port number to bind to. Hope that helped...